# How do I log out in chromium?

Tags: chromium

How do I log out of the Google account in Chromium.

After trying out the Google hangouts extension (which I have now uninstalled) I have my name displayed in the upper right side of Chromium windows, which means that I am logged into the Google account in some manner. I wish to log out.

When I press 'Manage people', I don't see any logout option. I do see a way to open another window as a guest, but that's not what I'm looking for. I want to logout of all the current windows and to no longer have my google account associated with the Chromium installation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

follow the below url:

chrome://settings/people

-> under the section 'People', click signout/turoff

Answer (score 5):

To remove your account from Chromium click on your name on the top right which should open a settings menu:

[image]

On choosing *Manage people* another window will pop up. On hovering the mouse to the top right corner of any account that is present on your Chromium installation you can click on a Hamburger menu that appeared there (three dots):

[image]

Choose *Remove this person* and proceed with a confirmation to have your account permanently removed.

> **Warning:** this will delete all of your account including saved passwords, extensions, history, etc. If you do not want this you should only sign out as depicted below.

---

To only temporarily surf with another account including a guest account you can choose to *sign out* or *add account* from the Google settings that appears in the Window:

[image]

Comment: WARNING: I have done this and it deleted all the settings of chromium, even those settings that were done before i logged in!! It even deleted things like extensions, saved passwords, etc.

Comment: @v010dya: sorry to hear that. I believe that would the difference between removing an account (1) and sign out of an account (2). The first usually is for privacy reasons where deleting all content is wanted.

Comment: I understand that. And i would have probably still deleted the account eventually after accidentally signing in, but the warning is necessary for other people.

Comment: @v010dya ah I see. I included the sign out part because of this but an additional warning is a good idea indeed.